# If data set has rows?

Tags: c#

I have one more question

I have this foreach statement:

```
foreach (DataRow dr_art_custsuply in ds.Tables["CustomerSupplier"].Rows)
{
    //Podaci iz CustomerSupplier-a

    //Id dobavljača
    string cust_id;
    if (!dr_art_custsuply.Table.Columns.Contains("Id"))
        cust_id = "";
    else if (dr_art_custsuply["Id"].ToString().Length <= 0)
        cust_id = "";
    else
        cust_id = dr_art_custsuply["Id"].ToString();

    //Naziv dobavljača
    string name;
    if (!dr_art_custsuply.Table.Columns.Contains("Name"))
        name = "";
    else if (dr_art_custsuply["Name"].ToString().Length <= 0)
        name = "";
    else
        name = dr_art_custsuply["Name"].ToString();  

   //GLN
   string gln;
   if (!dr_art_custsuply.Table.Columns.Contains("GLN"))
        gln = "";
   else if (dr_art_custsuply["GLN"].ToString().Length <= 0)
        gln = "";
   else
        gln = dr_art_custsuply["GLN"].ToString();
}
```

What I want to do is to check if ds.Tables["CustomerSupplier"].Rows exists, if not skip this for each, is it's there go trough code, I tried this if

```
(!ds.Tables.Contains("CustomerSupplier"))
{
}
```

but I got an error, so help help, how to write it?

Thanks!

Comment: Oded answer is correct. If there are no rows in your table then it will not even start the foreach loop.

Answer (score 5):

If there are no rows, you current code will already skip the body of the `foreach`.

```
foreach (DataRow dr_art_custsuply in ds.Tables["CustomerSupplier"].Rows)
```

That line will go to the end of the `foreach` and no code in the body will execute if there are no rows.

Update:

It wasn't entirely clear from your question, but it appears that you need to check if the *table* is actually in the dataset. Wrap the following `if` around the `foreach` to test for its existence:

```
if(ds.Tables["CustomerSupplier"] != null)
```

Comment: it gives me the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Are you sure there is a `CustomerSupplier` _table_ in the dataset?

Answer (score 2):

just add this check before your loop (It will not go in foreach if there are no rows)

```
if(ds.Tables["CustomerSupplier"].Rows.Count > 0)
```

Comment: If I write this I get: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'bool' because 'bool' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: @Bruno, you probably want to check if the ds.Tables["CustomerSupplier"] is null, and you have to put the if statement on top of foreach, not inside foreach

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the following condition before your **foreach**:

```
if(ds.Tables["CustomerSupplier"].Rows.Count > 0)
```

Comment: I done this but I still have an error on executing: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ????

Comment: Ok thanks the solution is this: if(ds.Tables["CustomerSupplier"] != null)
IT WORKS!!! thanks!!!